# Confluence - get amount of occurred name tags in a table over multiple conflence pages

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

I've a little question about Atlassian Confluence, queries and tables.
Consider the following:

- I've a Confluence page, called `CodeKata's`
- This main page has sub-pages like

  - 2020-January
  - 2020-February
  - ...
- These sub pages have a table with the following columns:

  - `[language | who | link to repository]`
  - the `who`-column has these Confluence name -tags, like `@Max Mustermann`

**Question:**
Is there a possibility to create on the main page `CodeKata's` a table, where I can query the occurrence of every name inside a table of the sub-pages?

Something like this:

```
Name            | Solved CodeKata's
-----------------------------------
@Max Mustermann | 4
-----------------------------------
@Suzi Sunshine  | 6
-----------------------------------
@Peter Parker   | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with a base confluence installation.
You could use the page properties macro on your kata pages, and then get an overview of all the data on your kata homepage.
But this will not give you the count, for this you could use the "table filter and charts" add-on.

Another option would be to write a custom macro to do this. Either by writing a user macro sending a REST request (to the still undocumented detailsummary endpoint, see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-38102) or a custom macro directly getting this info.

So, it can be done, but requires some effort.